# Why does a folder dialog immediately close unless a window is displayed in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, dialog

I'm developing a WPF application that's meant to live in the tool tray, so it doesn't involve any windows. Right-clicking the tool tray icon brings up a menu with a `Configure Report Path...` option, and I'd like to display a folder browser dialog to the user when this is clicked:

[image]

What I'm finding is that when the option is selected, a dialog opens and immediately closes unless I assign some window to `Application.Current.MainWindow` and show it before opening the dialog. This is the code I'm using:

```
public CounterIconViewModel(IMessenger messenger)
{
    void ConfigureReportPath()
    {
        // Application window must be created and displayed.
        Application.Current.MainWindow = new Window();
        Application.Current.MainWindow.Show();

        var browseDialog = new VistaFolderBrowserDialog { ShowNewFolderButton = false };

        if (browseDialog.ShowDialog() != true)
        {
            return;
        }

        // (Separate issue) Command doesn't execute unless I comment out the line below.
        //messenger.Send(browseDialog.SelectedPath, "ReportPath");
    }

    ConfigureReportPathCommand = new RelayCommand(ConfigureReportPath);
    ExitApplicationCommand = new RelayCommand(Application.Current.Shutdown);
}
```

In this case I'm using `VistaFolderBrowserDialog` from `Ookii.Dialogs.Wpf`, but I've tried the same thing with another WPF browser dialog and notice identical behaviour.

Is there a reason why a browser dialog seems to require a window to be displayed to remain open, and any workarounds?

**Update**

I've found that if I initialize and pass an instance of `Window` to `browseDialog.ShowDialog`, the dialog remains open without me having to assign the main application window and display it:

```
if (browseDialog.ShowDialog(new Window()) != true)
```

I don't understand why this works. I'll post this as an answer if no others appear so that at least people in a similar situation are aware of this workaround.

**Update 2**

The other dialog I tested it with was `CommonOpenFileDialog` from `Microsoft.WindowsApiCodePack-Shell`:

```
var browseDialog = new CommonOpenFileDialog { IsFolderPicker = true };
browseDialog.ShowDialog();
```

My tool tray icon displays a rich tool-tip (a custom UserControl) if I hover over it, and with this browser dialog I found that:

- If I hover over the icon to make the tool-tip display, then the browser dialog works fine when I try to open it on the first and every subsequent attempt.
- If I try to open the browser dialog *before* displaying the tool-tip display, the browser dialog opens and closes immediately on the first try, but then remains open on every subsequent attempt.

This dialog also accepts a `Window` instance in `ShowDialog` but it makes no difference if I pass one or not.

My workaround (initializing and passing a blank window to the Ookli dialog browser) seems to work fine regardless of whether I first bring up the tool-tip, so I'm sticking with that for the time being.

Comment: It sounds like a quirk of that particular library that contains that dialog.

Comment: Like I said in the post though, I've tried it with another dialog from a different library (can't remember which off the top of my head) and it behaved similarly.

Comment: Well in general, there is no rule that a dialog must have an owner. By default, a dialog without an owner is considered to be owned by the "desktop" conceptually. Perhaps certain dialogs impose a restriction that they will only operate if they have an owner, but I really have no idea. I have never encountered anything like that, but I have also never used any third party dialogs. Perhaps there is no message loop running in the thread that is spawning the dialog and the dialog is not creating its own.

Comment: @Xavier I remembered, the other dialog I tried with was the one from Windows API Code Pack - Shell. I've given it another shot and the behaviour was different from what I remembered, though. I've updated the post with further details (if you're interested).

Comment: The evidence seems to suggest the lack of a dispatcher running in the thread that is spawning the dialogs. Have you tried opening the dialog using the application's main dispatcher? `Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => dialogResult = dialog.ShowDialog())`

Comment: @Xavier makes no difference to behaviour i.e. continues to fail if I don't pass a new window, continues to work fine if I do.

Comment: The entire callback is executed on the main thread, which I believe is the UI thread that the dispatcher's associated with anyway.

Comment: Based on your description, I am guessing your application does not have a main window. If not, then it is possible that your application is running waiting to finish starting up. The default project template for a WPF app creates an App.xaml that generates an entry point which runs an application until its main window is closed. You may want to delete that and write your own entry point where you have more control over the main dispatcher. Alternatively, you can stick with your workaround since spawning a window will do a lot dispatcher stuff for you.

Comment: @Xavier No it doesn't have any windows, it just exists in the toolbar. I believe I've already accounted for this though by removing `StartupUri` from `App.xaml` and adding `ShutdownMode="OnExplicitShutdown"`.

Comment: Yes that is probably fine then, but I suspect something is not in the right state until at least one Window has been spawned. It would be a matter of investigating what that is at this point.