# Why does capturing free variables in the closure of a WPF command cause it to not run?

Tags: c#, wpf

#### Summary

I'm developing a WPF application that lives in the tool tray and there's a snippet of code in it that's exhibiting a lot of unusual (to me) behaviour. I've just about [sorted out one issue with it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49652633/why-does-a-folder-dialog-immediately-close-unless-a-window-is-displayed-in-wpf) so I'm moving on to the next.

Essentially, my problem is that the callback for one of my WPF commands doesn't seem to execute when I try to invoke it unless I comment out all references to free variables in its closure. I've posted the code below to explain what I mean by this.

#### Details

When I right-click my app's tool tray icon, it brings up a context menu containing items I bind to commands exposed by a view-model class. These bindings are defined in `App.xaml`:

```
<ContextMenu x:Shared="false" x:Key="SysTrayMenu">
    <MenuItem Header="Configure Report Path..." Command="{Binding ConfigureReportPathCommand}" />
    <MenuItem Header="Exit" Command="{Binding ExitApplicationCommand}" />
</ContextMenu>
```

I define the corresponding view-model as this:

```
public class CounterIconViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public CounterIconViewModel(IMessenger messenger)
    {
        void ConfigureReportPath()
        {
            var browseDialog = new VistaFolderBrowserDialog { ShowNewFolderButton = false };

            // Passing a new window is necessary to keep the dialog alive for some reason.
            if (browseDialog.ShowDialog(new Window()) != true)
            {
                return;
            }

            // Command doesn't execute unless I comment out the line below.
            //messenger.Send(browseDialog.SelectedPath, "ReportPath");
        }

        ConfigureReportPathCommand = new RelayCommand(ConfigureReportPath);
        ExitApplicationCommand = new RelayCommand(Application.Current.Shutdown);
    }

    public ICommand ConfigureReportPathCommand { get; }

    public ICommand ExitApplicationCommand { get; }
}
```

In this code, `messenger` is a free variable in the closure of `ConfigureReportPath`. If I comment out the references to it (as I've done in this snippet), then the command executes fine. However, if I uncomment these references and try to invoke the command in the same way, then nothing happens at all.

For what it's worth, `RelayCommand` is provided by [MVVM Light Toolkit](http://mvvmlight.net/).

**What I've tried**

I've tried storing `messenger` as a field and referencing the field in the closure instead:

```
private readonly IMessenger _messenger;

public CounterIconViewModel(IMessenger messenger)
{
    _messenger = messenger;

    void ConfigureReportPath()
    {
        var browseDialog = new VistaFolderBrowserDialog { ShowNewFolderButton = false };

        // Passing a new window is necessary to keep the dialog alive for some reason.
        if (browseDialog.ShowDialog(new Window()) != true)
        {
            return;
        }

        _messenger.Send(browseDialog.SelectedPath, "ReportPath");
    }

    ConfigureReportPathCommand = new RelayCommand(ConfigureReportPath);
    ExitApplicationCommand = new RelayCommand(Application.Current.Shutdown);
}
```

This works fine, so if nothing else I have this to fall back on.

I've also just tried creating a local variable in the view-model constructor and referencing it in the closure. With this I've been able to verify that the command fails to execute if seemingly *any* free variables are used in it (as opposed to the possibility that it's just something funky with `messenger`):

```
public CounterIconViewModel(IMessenger messenger)
{
    var foo = "bar";

    void ConfigureReportPath()
    {
        var browseDialog = new VistaFolderBrowserDialog { ShowNewFolderButton = false };

        // Passing a new window is necessary to keep the dialog alive for some reason.
        if (browseDialog.ShowDialog(new Window()) != true)
        {
            return;
        }

        // Also needs to be commented out to allow command to execute.
        //var bar = foo.Length;
    }

    ConfigureReportPathCommand = new RelayCommand(ConfigureReportPath);
    ExitApplicationCommand = new RelayCommand(Application.Current.Shutdown);
}
```

**Update**

One other thing I've just tried is passing the messenger from the constructor to the nested method as a parameter:

```
public CounterIconViewModel(IMessenger messenger)
{
    void ConfigureReportPath(IMessenger nestedMessenger)
    {
        // ...
    }

    ConfigureReportPathCommand = new RelayCommand(() => ConfigureReportPath(messenger));
}
```

This prevents the command from firing regardless of whether I reference `nestedMessenger` or not. If I make the parameter a string instead and do `new RelayCommand(() => ConfigureReportPath("foo"))`, it works fine.

Comment: Wat version of `MVVM Light toolkit` do you use? It seems that there was [issues with closure and RelayCommand](http://www.mvvmlight.net/installing/changes)

Comment: Messenger is a variable that you'd have to pass in go the viewmodel constructor. You seem to think it will be captured from somewhere.

Comment: @Troopers I'm at home now (can't access the repo) but all my dependencies are up-to-date so I assume the latest version published on NuGet (5.4.1). However, thanks for pointing me in the right direction, [this](http://www.mvvmlight.net/doc/weakaction.cshtml) looks useful.

Comment: @Andy not sure what you mean, where `messenger` comes from is irrelevant, the point is just that if it appears in the closure of `ConfigureReportPath` and it's not a parameter or local variable of that function, then it's a free variable i.e. captured.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So there are several things going on here.
First it is important to know that MVVM Light, by default, only maintains a weak reference to the `Execute` and `CanExecute` delegates. This is true for both the `GalaSoft.MvvmLight.CommandWpf.RelayCommand` and `GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command.RelayCommand` classes. This is ultimately the reason why your execute delegate is not being called, because the command only holds a weak reference to it, the garbage collector is cleaning it up.

So then the question is, why is it being cleaned up?
First we need to understand what is happening when you write `new RelayCommand(ConfigureReportPath)`. The `RelayCommand` constructor parameter is an `Action` so the compiler converts the method to an Action delegate. This is equivalent to:

```
new RelayCommand(new Action(ConfigureReportPath));
```

In IL you will see the calls

```
ldtfn <method pointer>
newobj instance void [mscorlib]System.Action::.ctor(object, native int)
```

Take a look at the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/local-functions-vs-lambdas). There is a hidden line near the top:

> ... lambda expressions are converted to delegates when they are declared. Local functions are converted to delegates only when used as a delegate.

The key here is because you are using local functions as the parameter to a `RelayCommand` they will always be converted to a delegate (`Action`) type.

The next problem is then the local function. You will notice that if you convert your ConfigureReportPath to an instance method on your view model your problem will also go away (this will also require storing the IMessenger instance in a field).
When you write:

```
public CounterIconViewModel(IMessenger messenger)
{
    void ConfigureReportPath()
    {
        ...
        messenger.Send(...);
    }

    ConfigureReportPathCommand = new RelayCommand(ConfigureReportPath);
}
```

What actually gets compiled is something like this (note that the compile is generating the IL; I am converting back to a rough C# equivalent)

```
public class CounterIconViewModel
{
    private sealed class Generated
    {
        public IMessenger messenger;

        void ConfigureReportPath()
        {
            ...
            messenger.Send(...);
        }
    }

    public CounterIconViewModel(IMessenger messenger)
    {
        var generated = new Generated();
        generated.messenger = messenger;
        ConfigureReportPathCommand = new RelayCommand(new Action(generated.ConfigureReportPath));
    }
}
```

In this form it is a bit more obvious what is happening. The generated inner class contains the actual execute method for the command. The implicit `Action` is the only thing that hold a reference to it and the `RelayCommand` is the only thing that hold a reference to the `Action`. Since the `RelayCommand` only holds a weak reference to the `Action` the garbage collector is free to clean it up after execution leaves your view model's constructor.

Another way to look at it is as if you wrote it as a delegate in the first place:

```
public CounterIconViewModel(IMessenger messenger)
{
    ConfigureReportPathCommand = new RelayCommand(() => 
    {
        ...
        messenger.Send(...);
    });
}
```

Again, in this form it is a bit more obvious why the delegate would be garbage collected. Because the only thing being captured is the constructor parameter, as soon as that goes out of scope the delegate can be cleaned up.

Let's also take a look at what happens when you store the `IMessenger` in a field (just like your second attempt).

```
public class CounterIconViewModel
{
    private readonly IMessenger _messenger;

    public CounterIconViewModel(IMessenger messenger)
    {
        _messenger = messenger;

        void ConfigureReportPath()
        {
            ...
            _messenger.Send(...);
        }

        ConfigureReportPathCommand = new RelayCommand(ConfigureReportPath);
    }
}
```

In this case the local function needs access to a private field in the containing type. This will cause the local function to be generated like this:

```
public class CounterIconViewModel
{
    private readonly IMessenger _messenger;

    private void ConfigureReportPath()
    {
        ...
        _messenger.Send(...);
    }

    public CounterIconViewModel(IMessenger messenger)
    {
        _messenger = messenger;

        ConfigureReportPathCommand = new RelayCommand(new Action(ConfigureReportPath);
    }
}
```

Because the local function is created as an instance method on the view model, it will live as long as your view model does. I have never been able to locate good documentation on how the compiler is expected to treat local functions (aside from the implementation itself in Roselyn). If anyone knows of such documentation I would love to see it.

**Potential Solutions**

- Simply re-write your local functions as instance methods on your view model. I tend to favor this approach as I find it the easiest to read, and also comes with the fewest weird issues.
- Use the optional parameter on `RelayCommand`. There is also an optional boolean parameter on `RelayCommand` named "keepTargetAlive". It defaults to `false` but if you set it to true it will cause the `RelayCommand` to hold onto its delegates as strong references rather than weak references. Be careful with this option as it does open up the potential of memory leaks. It comes down to what is actually captured as part of your delegates. The key is to keep track of the objects that are being captured.

Answer (score 2):

See http://www.mvvmlight.net/doc/weakaction.cshtml

If you use a closure, you have to tell the RelayCommand to "keepTargetAlive".

```
ConfigureReportPathCommand = new RelayCommand(ConfigureReportPath, keepTargetAlive: true);
```

From RelayCommand.cs

```
public virtual void Execute(object parameter)
{
    if (CanExecute(parameter)
        && _execute != null
        && (_execute.IsStatic || _execute.IsAlive))
    {
        _execute.Execute();
    }
}
```

Without keepTargetAlive set to true, _execute.IsStatic is false and _execute.IsAlive is false so it doesn't execute.

Note that the RelayCommand constructor states that it might cause a memory leak. It doesn't state how to avoid it... I guess make sure to set ConfigureReportPathCommand to null when you're done?

> keepTargetAlive:
>       If true, the target of the Action will be kept as a hard reference, which might
>       cause a memory leak. You should only set this parameter to true if the action
>       is causing a closure. See http://galasoft.ch/s/mvvmweakaction.

Comment: Thanks, you posted this exactly 5 seconds after I discovered this haha. I'll upvote this now & accept it when I get a chance to confirm this tomorrow.

Comment: Hah, at least it should resolve your issue. I mocked up an example based on your code (passing IMessenger in constructor) and it did not work until keepTargetAlive was set to true.